# highcharts: change color of pie slice on hover

Tags: colors, highcharts, hover

when a slice of pie chart is hovered over i'd like it to change to the designated hover color, and then change back to its original color once the mouse is off that slice.

the documentation here (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.states.hover) made it seem like the following would work, but i didn't have any luck:

http://jsfiddle.net/pixeloco/ztJkb/3/

```
plotOptions: {
   series: {
      marker: {
        states: {
          hover: {
            fillColor: 'black'
          }
        }
      }
   }
},
```

i found this solution http://jsfiddle.net/r6p7E/6/, but it requires that all slices be the same color. is there a way to have a multi-colored chart with slices that change color on hover?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you need these options:

```
    series: {
        states: {
            hover: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        point: {
            events: {
                mouseOver: function () {
                    this.options.oldColor = this.color;
                    this.graphic.attr("fill", "black");
                },
                mouseOut: function () {
                    this.graphic.attr("fill", this.options.oldColor);
                }
            }
        },
    }
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ztJkb/4/)

Comment: perfect! this answers my original question but... any idea why this same approach would not work for a bar graph? http://jsfiddle.net/pixeloco/RPbjY/ the section does change on hover, but if hovered over more than once it does not return to original color

Comment: Change `this.options.oldColor = this.color;` to `this.options.oldColor = this.graphic.fill;` http://jsfiddle.net/RPbjY/2/